# Steps required to recognise a $z$-smooth number

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, smoothness

I am currently reading section 5 of Pomerance's paper [The Number Field Sieve](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper99.pdf) and I have a few questions about smooth numbers.

A number $x\in\mathbb Z_{\ge1}$ is called $z$-smooth if every prime divisor $p$ of $x$ satisfies $p\le z$. So if we want to check if a given natural number is $z$-smooth, we could simply trial divide by all prime numbers $p\le z$, which should take about $\pi(z)$ steps ($\pi$ = prime-counting function).

However, Pomerance states that it would take about $z$ steps, which I think should be $\pi(z)$ (as pointed out above). And he also states that using his *early abort strategy* one would need about $z^{1/2}$ steps, which I think should read $\pi(z)^{1/2}$.

I guess that I am missing his point, since he is a very accomplished number theorist, but I am not sure.

Comment: How many steps should it take to determine which of 110592 and 110596 is 5-smooth?  Does division come for free in your model?

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. But what does Pomerance mean, when he says "... trial division, taking about $z$ steps to recognize whether $s$ is $z$-smooth"? E.g. for your first number $110592=2^{12}\cdot 3^3$ we would need about $15=12+3$ divisons, and for $110596=2^2\cdot 43\cdot 643$ we would need about $4$ ($2$ for $2$, $1$ check for $3$, $1$ check for $5$).

Comment: To check by trial division if a number is $z$-smooth in $\pi(z)$ steps would require knowing all primes up to $z$. If you just trial divide by all numbers up to $z$ you avoid the extra cost of identifying the primes. Which is best will depend on this extra cost.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Since the algorithms described in Pomerance's paper require many number to be checked for smoothness I am assuming that we know all the primes up to z (e.g. they could be safed in an array). So I am still wondering what his statement means. :/

Comment: Perhaps instead of divide by p, perhaps a step is gcd with a large power of p.

Comment: $\pi(z)$ is about $z/\log(z)$, and I think he is just ignoring logs, either of $z$ or of $x$.  The main focus is on the power of $z$.

Comment: If you are going to check thousands of numbers of size $x \approx N$ to see if they are $z$ smooth then you can precompute the product $P$ of all primes up $z$ and then $x$ is $z$-smooth exactly if $\gcd(x,P)=1$  You peel off many prime factors at a time without knowing what they were. I suppose you could also start with $P_1$ just the primes up to $\sqrt{z}$ then if the $\gcd$ is less than $z$ you have $z$-smooth if it is between $z$ and $z^{3/2}$ then test if it is prime (not $z$-smooth) or composite. If the $\gcd$ is larger, then you might have to pull out $P_2$ for the larger primes.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz You probably mean that $x$ is $z$-smooth (and squarefree) if $gcd(x,P)=x$. Note that if you go for this approach, finding which $x$s are smooth in a list is going to be even more efficient (using remainder trees). Another option, frequently used in implementations of the number field sieve is to use the elliptic curve factoring algorithm (with a good early abort strategy) on $x$.